# how much certain mathematician has been cited in recent articles

Tags: galois-theory

I want to know how much Galois work has been cited in recent articles. So I'm looking for a tool that can help me do that, more simply is there a tool to know how much certain mathematician has been cited in recent articles ? (for modern mathematicians there is google scholar )

Comment: ams.org/mathscinet

Comment: @vadim123 this requires a login and password

Comment: Most universities have access, and will let anyone use their libraries.

Comment: I'm not a student..

Comment: Note the word 'anyone' in vadim123's comment.